# error setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add recyclerview in app like this

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:stackFromEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="215dp" />




 recyclerViewSlider = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSlider);
    recyclerViewSlider.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerViewSlider.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    productListSlider = new ArrayList<>();
```

Error

```
Output:  D:\Android\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxx\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:65: error: attribute stackFromEnd (aka xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx:stackFromEnd) not found.
```

error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recyclerview implementation on xml is wrong :

It must be

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:stackFromEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="215dp" />
```

And in your activity file you need to call it by using :

```
recyclerViewSlider = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView4 );
```

Comment: Though that's a very valid point, it will cause a runtime Exception, not the build error that the OP shows in the question.